# attachEvent versus addEventListener

Tags: javascript, cross-browser

I'm having troubles getting the attachEvent to work. In all browsers that support the addEventListener handler the code below works like a charm, but in IE is a complete disaster. They have their own (incomplete) variation of it called attachEvent.

Now here's the deal. How do I get the attachEvent to work in the same way addEventListener does?

Here's the code:

```
function aFunction(idname)
{
    document.writeln('<iframe id="'+idname+'"></iframe>');
    var Editor = document.getElementById(idname).contentWindow.document;

    /* Some other code */

    if (Editor.attachEvent)
    {
        document.writeln('<textarea id="'+this.idname+'" name="' + this.idname + '" style="display:none">'+this.html+'</textarea>');
        Editor.attachEvent("onkeyup", KeyBoardHandler);
    }
    else
    {
        document.writeln('<textarea id="hdn'+this.idname+'" name="' + this.idname + '" style="display:block">'+this.html+'</textarea>');
        Editor.addEventListener("keyup", KeyBoardHandler, true);
    }
}
```

This calls the function KeyBoardHandler that looks like this:

```
function KeyBoardHandler(Event, keyEventArgs) {
    if (Event.keyCode == 13) {
        Event.target.ownerDocument.execCommand("inserthtml",false,'<br />');
        Event.returnValue = false;
    }

    /* more code */
}
```

I don't want to use any frameworks because A) I'm trying to learn and understand something, and B) any framework is just an overload of code I'm nog going to use.

Any help is highly appreciated!

Comment: You have a good point with trying to learn without using a framework to understand the inner workings of browser-based JavaScript. However, I'd suggest that you move on to using frameworks for production code once you've mastered low-level JavaScript it does not make a lot of sense to reinvent the wheel (frameworks are widely tested with a variety of browsers, and once you roll your own framework, it will get large anyways to work around browser quirks and avoid boilerplate code elsewhere in your code). Plus, external JavaScript can be cached by the browser once for multiple requests.

Comment: what are you trying to do and what is happening now that is wrong?

Comment: Frameworks like jquery are more like a standard today, they try to make cross browser compatibility a real thing, use javascript when you actually want to do something specific and want full controll.

Answer (score 14):

Here's how to make this work cross-browser, just for reference though.

```
var myFunction=function(){
  //do something here
}
var el=document.getElementById('myId');

if (el.addEventListener) {
  el.addEventListener('mouseover',myFunction,false);
  el.addEventListener('mouseout',myFunction,false);
} else if(el.attachEvent) {
  el.attachEvent('onmouseover',myFunction);
  el.attachEvent('onmouseout',myFunction);
} else {
  el.onmouseover = myFunction;
  el.onmouseout = myFunction;
}
```

ref: http://jquerydojo.blogspot.com/2012/12/javascript-dom-addeventlistener-and.html

Answer (score 7):

The source of your problems is the `KeyBoardHandler` function. Specifically, in IE `Event` objects do not have a `target` property: the equivalent is `srcElement`. Also, the `returnValue` property of `Event` objects is IE-only. You want the `preventDefault()` method in other browsers.

```
function KeyBoardHandler(evt, keyEventArgs) {
    if (evt.keyCode == 13) {
        var target = evt.target || evt.srcElement;
        target.ownerDocument.execCommand("inserthtml",false,'<br />');
        if (typeof evt.preventDefault != "undefined") {
            evt.preventDefault();
        } else {
            evt.returnValue = false;
        }
    }

    /* more code */
}
```

Answer (score 2):

Just use a framework like jQuery or prototype. That's what they are there for, this exact reason: being able to do this sort of thing w/out having to worry about cross-browser compatibility.  It's super easy to install...just include a .js script and add a line of code...

(edited just for you Crescent Fresh)

With a framework, the code is as simple as...

```
<script type='text/javascript' src='jquery.js'></script>
$('element').keyup(function() { 
  // stuff to happen on event here
});
```

Comment: seriously though...go pickup jQuery or something...I used to resist it for the longest time...one day I was forced to learn it to the extent of fixing some code that utilized it...ever since then...I constantly kick myself in the arse for not using it sooner.  Greatest invention since sliced bread.

Comment: Why don't you show the OP how crazy easy it is to do with jQuery or Prototype then! "Just use jQuery" ain't no kind of answer.

Comment: happy?  I didn't think something that "crazy easy" needed explaining but since you want to be an arse like you're some kind of interweb police person...p.s. - thanks for the downvote, glad I made your self-righteous day a little brighter.

Comment: @Crayon you don't know whether Crescent Fresh actually cast that downvote. +1 because I agree though

Comment: Let's keep it friendly please, no need to fight over such a stupid little thing. ;-)

Comment: In crescent Fresh's defense I'm fairly new to JS and I'm researching this as well and your answer wasn't an answer. even after you added the code snippet the lack of explanation made it no help at all. just saying.

Answer (score 2):

Here is a function I use for both browsers:

```
function eventListen(t, fn, o) {
    o = o || window;
    var e = t+Math.round(Math.random()*99999999);
    if ( o.attachEvent ) {
        o['e'+e] = fn;
        o[e] = function(){
            o['e'+e]( window.event );
        };
        o.attachEvent( 'on'+t, o[e] );
    }else{
        o.addEventListener( t, fn, false );
    }
}
```

And you can use it like:

```
eventListen('keyup', function(ev){
  if (ev.keyCode === 13){
    ...
  }
  ...
}, Editor)
```

Comment: What would the converse `detachEvent`/`removeEventListener` look like? (you know, for symmetry's sake).

Comment: So how would I use the code above in this case? Sorry, somewhat of a JS noob. :/

Comment: @user451513, I've updated the example to look like yours. Is it your question?

Comment: @Mic; it doesn't work unfortunately. Can I e-mail you the entire code so you can see the purpose?

Comment: Yep. Post it somewhere like http://friendpaste.com, but quick it is near bedtime here ;)

Comment: Here's a small example that works on IE and others http://gist.github.com/586091 I'll check yours

Comment: Inside the callback function there are differences with IE. eg: `event.srcElement` while all other browsers use `event.target`, you may need as well to abstract these like `var target = ev.target || ev.srcElement` Good Night!

Comment: Thanks Mic, now I see what I've learned something and fixed the problem.

Comment: Good! Welcome to the client-side of the web! Keep PHP to read/generate JSON messages, and do the view with JS and HTML on the browser 8)

Answer (score 2):

Different browsers will process events differently. Some browsers have event bubble up throw the controls where as some go top down. For more information on that take a look at this W3C doc: http://www.w3.org/TR/DOM-Level-3-Events/#event-flow

As for this specific issue setting the "userCapture" parameter to false for the addEventListener will make events behave the same as Internet Explorer: https://developer.mozilla.org/en/DOM/element.addEventListener#Internet_Explorer

Comment: `useCapture` only determines if the event fires during the capture sequence or bubble sequence. IE only does the bubble sequence, so `false` is used for compatibility. it won't change the process of the handler.

Answer (score 0):

You might be better off using a JavaScript framework such as [MooTools](http://mootools.net/) or [jQuery](http://jquery.com/) of your choice to ease cross-browser support. For details, see also

- http://mootools.net/docs/core/Element/Element.Event
- http://api.jquery.com/category/events/

MooTools port of parts of your sample code:

```
var Editor = $(idname).contentWindow.document;
...
$(document.body).grab(new Element('textarea', {
    'id'   : this.idname,
    'name' : this.idname,
    'style': 'display:none;',
    'html' : this.html
});
Editor.addEvent('keyup', KeyBoardHandler);
```

By the way, is it on purpose that you use both `idname` and `this.idname` in the code above ?

Comment: Thanks guys, but no thanks. ;-) First of all I'm trying to learn something here, secondly I don't want an overload of code that I'm not going to use. So please no external framework advice, although I understand the idea behind it.

Comment: I mean this with the best of intentions - maybe it would be better to learn not the quirks of the underlying browsers, but to instead spend your time learning higher-level concepts like callbacks, promises, the module pattern, currying, etc. As browsers become more standardised, your ROI on learning such specifics will diminish, whereas learning more abstract Javascript ideas is just as satisfying to learn while at the same time equipping you for other languages and different things down the track.