# Load a function immediately - no access to <body>

Tags: javascript, load, onload

I need to load a function as soon as a page loads, but I am working with a CMS that does not provide me access to the BODY tag.  So I am not able to load it on the body, but in the content of the page.  Any suggestions on the best way of loading a function in the content of the page?

I prefer to have it in regular Javascript, Jquery has been causing problems with the site as well.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use

```
window.onload = function() {
   ...
};
```

As Quentin commented, you can also use [`addEventListener` or `attachEvent`](https://stackoverflow.com/a/13870650/1916258).

Comment: The drawback to this approach is that it will overwrite anything that might be there already. `addEventListener` (with the compatibility routines mentioned in the MDN documentation) is safer.

Answer (score 2):

If you don't need to wait until the DOM is ready.

```
<script> function_call(); </script>
```

Otherwise bind it to the load event with [`addEventListener`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/DOM/element.addEventListener).