# How can I catch a click event objects attribute using javascript only?

Tags: javascript

I have the following coded using jQuery:

```
$('.status-infos').click( function (e) {
    var xx = $(this).attr('data-xx');
    alert(xx);
    return false;
  });
```

Our site main page will no longer use jQuery and so I need to do something similar to this using only javascript.

I saw this as a way to get the click event:

```
document.getElementById('element').onclick = function(e){
  alert('click');
}
```

but how can I get the xx attribute.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

jQuery has always made developers lazy.. Try this code:

```
/* http://dustindiaz.com/rock-solid-addevent */
function addEvent(obj, type, fn) {
    if (obj.addEventListener) {
        obj.addEventListener(type, fn, false);
        EventCache.add(obj, type, fn);
    }

    else if (obj.attachEvent) {
        obj["e" + type + fn] = fn;
        obj[type + fn] = function() {
            obj["e" + type + fn](window.event);
        }
        obj.attachEvent("on" + type, obj[type + fn]);
        EventCache.add(obj, type, fn);
    }
    else {
        obj["on" + type] = obj["e" + type + fn];
    }
}
var EventCache = function() {
    var listEvents = [];
    return {
        listEvents: listEvents,
        add: function(node, sEventName, fHandler) {
            listEvents.push(arguments);
        },
        flush: function() {
            var i, item;
            for (i = listEvents.length - 1; i >= 0; i = i - 1) {
                item = listEvents[i];
                if (item[0].removeEventListener) {
                    item[0].removeEventListener(item[1], item[2], item[3]);
                };
                if (item[1].substring(0, 2) != "on") {
                    item[1] = "on" + item[1];
                };
                if (item[0].detachEvent) {
                    item[0].detachEvent(item[1], item[2]);
                };
                item[0][item[1]] = null;
            };
        }
    };
}();
/* http://www.dustindiaz.com/getelementsbyclass */
function getElementsByClass(searchClass,node,tag) {
    var classElements = new Array();
    if ( node == null )
        node = document;
    if ( tag == null )
        tag = '*';
    var els = node.getElementsByTagName(tag);
    var elsLen = els.length;
    var pattern = new RegExp("(^|\\s)"+searchClass+"(\\s|$)");
    for (i = 0, j = 0; i < elsLen; i++) {
        if ( pattern.test(els[i].className) ) {
            classElements[j] = els[i];
            j++;
        }
    }
    return classElements;
}
var statuss=getElementsByClass('status-infos');
for (var i=0;i<statuss.length;i++){
addEvent(statuss[i], 'click', function (e) {
    var xx = this.getAttribute('data-xx');
    alert(xx);
    return false;
  });
}
```

[Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/mMhXV/1/show) | [Demo Source](http://jsfiddle.net/mMhXV/1/)

Answer (score 2):

You can use:

`document.getElementsByClassName('status-infos')`

Then loop over that array and use.. `onclick = function() {}`

Use: `element.getAttribute()` to get the data attribute

Comment: Thanks but how do I do the loop and how can I get the data-xx attribute?

Answer (score 1):

Solution for modern browsers:

```
var els = document.querySelectorAll(".status-infos");
for (var i = 0; i < els.length; i++) {
    els[i].addEventListener("click", function() {
        var xx = this.getAttribute("data-xx");
        alert(xx);
        return false;
    });
}
```

Comment: @VisionN - Thanks. When you say "modern". How modern do you mean? Will it for example work with IE7 ?  Just out of interest, why do you name the variable els ?

Comment: @Anne No, IE7 doesn't support [`addEventListener`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/DOM/element.addEventListener), it should be replaced with `attachEvent`. We can define compatibility for IE > 8, while Chrome and Firefox should work fine with it.

Comment: @VisionN - Thanks. Is there a way that I could make this work for both IE7 and the modern browsers?

Comment: @Anne It is easier to use jQuery then :) The basic idea of jQuery is to provide **cross browser** compatibility. BTW, `els` is just `elements` in short.

Answer (score 1):

Here is the complete version for IE8+ as well

[DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/mplungjan/K9k95/)

```
function getElementsByClassName(className) {
if (document.getElementsByClassName) { 
  return document.getElementsByClassName(className); }
else { return document.querySelectorAll('.' + className); } }

window.onload=function() {
  var statinf = getElementsByClassName("status-infos");
  for (var i=0;i<statinf.length;i++) {
    statinf[i].onclick=function() {
      var xx = this.getAttribute('data-xx');
      alert(xx);
      return false;
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: So I don't need to add or attach an event listener like the other answers suggest?

Comment: Maybe it is easier to use `querySelectorAll` instead of `getElementsByClassName` from the start, since the first is supported from IE8, while the second from IE9 only.

Answer (score 0):

Use an [`addEventListener`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/DOM/element.addEventListener) or [`attachEvent` (IE)](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ie/ms536343%28v=vs.85%29.aspx).

```
var elements = document.getElementByClassName('status-infos');

for(var i=0; i < elements.length; i++) {
   elements[i].addEventListener('click', function(e) {
    ...
    });
}
```

[More info](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3743446/attachevent-versus-addeventlistener)