# Converting as3 btn code to Javascript

Tags: javascript, html, actionscript-3, html5-canvas, flash-cc

I am attempting to convert a flash as3 file to canvas html5 doc with javascript.

How would I convert this code below?

```
nex.addEventListener(MouseEvent.CLICK, onClickHandler);

function onClickHandler(myEvent:MouseEvent)
{
    SoundMixer.stopAll();
    MovieClip(parent).nextFrame();
}
```

My javascript attempt that is now working.

```
this.nex.onClick = function(){

 exportRoot.play();

}
```

Thanks for the help!

Comment: there is no onClick event, there is an onclick event.

Comment: Thanks i fixed that "C" to "c"... Still no success and getting it to go to the root and play the next frame.

Comment: Any errors in the console? What is `this.nex`? What is `exportRoot`? You need to make a running example.

Comment: nex is the name of my button instance in flash. exportRoot was a bit of code I found that i think is suppose to bring you back to the root level.

Comment: well nex should be an object reference to the DOM. And exportRoot is nothing in JavaScript unless that is some framework you included.

Comment: So do you know how i reference the root? Im not sure what a object reference to a DOM is either. never wrote any javascript.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Here is the proper code to use for buttons now in a html5 flash project

```
this.Next.addEventListener("click", fl_ClickToGoToAndStopAtFrame_7.bind(this));

function fl_ClickToGoToAndStopAtFrame_7() {

    this.gotoAndStop(1);

}
```

Answer (score 1):

I'm not trying to be pedantic, but your problem is not likely as simple as converting ActionScript 3.0 to JavaScript. AS3 is for the most part a superset of JavaScript (see [ECMAcSript 4](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ECMAScript#ECMAScript.2C_4th_Edition)), so converting "down" to JavaScript is easy:

```
nex.addEventListener(MouseEvent.CLICK, onClickHandler);

function onClickHandler(myEvent)
{
    SoundMixer.stopAll();
    MovieClip(parent).nextFrame();
}
```

Almost looks the same, right? You just removed the `MouseEvent` type declaration on `myEvent`, because type declarations are a ECMAScript 4 feature that never made it into JS (sadly).

The real problem is that the browser API and the Flash Player API are very different. And even where they may be similar, they aren't necessarily similar in all browsers. Now to be fair, I think this was really your original question, I just wanted to point out that the road ahead involves knowing a lot about the differences between Flash Player features and browser features, because that's where most of the work will be. That actual conversion of syntax should not be too hard.

Going back to your example, here are a few differences to point out:

1) While [`addEventListener()`](http://www.w3schools.com/jsref/met_document_addeventlistener.asp) is a valid browser method (contrary to what a commenter said) it isn't supported in older browsers such as IE8. In that case you can use `attachEvent()`, and as a final fallback you can use the DOM callback `onClick`. [More explanation here.](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3743446/attachevent-versus-addeventlistener)

2) While `MouseEvent` exists in one form or another in the browser, there are no static constants in JS, so you will not find things like `MouseEvent.CLICK` defined by the browser. Instead you'll just use the string `"click"`.

3) `SoundMixer` is a Flash Player feature. It's closest equivalent in the browser will be [HTML5 audio](http://www.w3schools.com/html/html5_audio.asp). There are a lot of differences here, it's no easy to task to do audio in the browser, and you simply won't have the same amount of abilities as the Flash Player sound APIs. I would look for a library that makes browser audio easier to work with.

4) `MovieClip` is a Flash Player feature. There is no near equivalent in the browser. There's really no easy answer here for how you should re-create your timeline-like stuff in the browser, but libraries like [CreateJS](http://createjs.com/) (created by Flash users) or tools like [Adobe Edge Animate](https://creative.adobe.com/products/animate), or using [Adobe Flash Pro's own HTML output features](https://helpx.adobe.com/flash/using/creating-publishing-html5-canvas-document.html) might help you re-create things for the browser.

**EDIT:** Aha, it wasn't clear to me from your question but since you tagged this [flash-cc] it sounds like you are already using Adobe Flash Pro CC's HTML Canvas document? In that case, all of the above still applies, but in addition you will be able to use Flash Pro's timeline JS library. This is a combination of CreateJS and some extra stuff that Adobe created to simulate many of the Flash Player timeline behaviors within the browser, which doesn't have a timeline built in. For more on this, I would start here: https://helpx.adobe.com/flash/using/creating-publishing-html5-canvas-document.html