# What is the difference between addEventListener and attachEvent?

Tags: javascript

This is the code i used in my page,

```
if (window.addEventListener) {
   window.addEventListener("load", createIframe, false);            
}
else if (window.attachEvent) {
   window.attachEvent("onload", createIframe);            
}
else {
   window.onload = createIframe;           
}
```

Please explain me that where my **createIframe** funtion get called? and what is the difference between *addEventListener* and *attachEvent*? and what is the different between *load* and *onload*? totally confused to find difference between **addEventLisener with load and attachEvent with onload**

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3743446/attachevent-versus-addeventlistener?rq=1

Answer (score 63, accepted):

Quick answer: you have to use `attachEvent` if your browser returns `undefined == window.addEventListener`. Thing is the former is a non-standard JS function implemented in IE8 and previous versions, while `addEventListener` is supported by IE9+ (and all the other browsers).

So the big question is: are you gonna support IE8-?

Margin note: `window.onload = whatever` will override any attached event listeners. This is why `addEventListener` is used: to add a function to the event's stack, instead of overwriting it.

Comment: Can babel be used to transpile addEventListener for older browsers? The preset-env doesn't seem to do it..